# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: maven-2, slf4j

I'm getting the following error. It seems there are multiple logging frameworks bound to slf4j. Not sure how to resolve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Comment: **Resolved** Using   `<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>`  
in the dependecies (of pom.xml) that caused conflict helped resolve the problem

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921382/maven-slf4j-version-conflict-when-using-two-different-dependencies-that-requi

Comment: Did you already check http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings as stated in the warning?

Comment: Maybe It could be better to add an answer (auto-answer) to this question and mark it as "Accepted", So the question will appear as "Solved" in the SO searchs

Comment: Roberto, Thanks for feedback. I copied the solution from the comment and posted it as answer.

Comment: I am getting the same error but in Pom.xml file we don't have slf4j dependency.

Comment: For future readers, here is a good article for log4j2 (<<emphasis on the "2" here)  https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/log4j2.html  the key phrase in the article is : "spring-boot-starter-log4j2 is a starter for using Log4j2. It is an alternative to spring-boot-starter-logging."

Comment: Add exclude dependency with the dependency which has been placed at first.

Answer (score 170):

Resolved by adding the following exclusion in the dependencies (of pom.xml) that caused conflict.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Comment: which dependancy caused conflict in this case, I have dependancy tree there are 3 mentions of slf4j

Comment: to find out how log4j is getting on your path run mvn dependency:tree and comb through, then add the snippet above to that dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: @user1493140 Still it is not working for me.
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions> 
</dependency>

Comment: for me another jar war the cause. I had to exclude the artifacts with id slf4j-nop and  slf4j-jdk14. The dependency that caused the conflict for me was clover-maven-plugin

Comment: is the version (`slf4j-log4j12`) applicable for all? or should we find out the version from **mvn dependency:tree**?

Answer (score 88):

Gradle version;

```
configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```

Comment: Importing Models from the main application into automation framework.. this resolved my problem with gradle. ty.

Comment: Is there any ant version of doing this ?

Comment: no: ant is not a dependency aware tool. Strongly consider porting your build to gradle.

Comment: strongly recomend porting your build to sbt :)

Comment: How to do in Maven?

Comment: @ParthaPaul the previous answer is the one for that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638585/1505341

Comment: I had to add `exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'`

Answer (score 42):

The error probably gives more information like this (although your jar names could be different)

> SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/D:/Java/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/D:/Java/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.8.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Noticed that the conflict comes from two jars, named `logback-classic-1.2.3` and `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar`.

Run `mvn dependency:tree` in this project pom.xml parent folder, giving:

[image: dependency tree conflict]

Now choose the one you want to ignore (could consume a delicate endeavor I need more help on this)

I decided not to use the one imported from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` (the top dependency) through `spring-boot-starter` and through `spring-boot-starter-logging`, pom becomes:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

in above pom `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` would use the `spring-boot-starter` configured in the same file, which excludes `logging` (it contains `logback`)

Comment: Thank you for introducing `mvn dependency:tree`. It's so much helpful...

Comment: Thank you for providing the reasoning. As each case is different, the reasoning helped my case.

Comment: you can find this answer in a more general explanation here, this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-classpath-multiple-bindings) helped me solve my issue as explained in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Sbt version:

Append `exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")` to the dependency that transitively includes `slf4j-log4j12`. For example, when using Spark with Log4j 2.6:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // One SLF4J implementation (log4j-slf4j-impl) is here:
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.6.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.6.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.6.1",
  // The other implementation (slf4j-log4j12) would be transitively
  // included by Spark. Prevent that with exclude().
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1" exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
)
```

Comment: What does Sbt stand for?

Comment: Simple Build Tool*

Answer (score 9):

1.Finding the conflicting jar

If it's not possible to identify the dependency from the warning, then you can use the following command to identify the conflicting jar

```
mvn dependency: tree
```

This will display the dependency tree for the project and dependencies who have pulled in another binding with the `slf4j-log4j12` JAR.

2. Resolution

Now that we know the offending dependency, all that we need to do is exclude the `slf4j-log4j12` JAR from that dependency.

Ex - if `spring-security` dependency has also pulled in another binding with the `slf4j-log4j12` JAR, Then we need to exclude the `slf4j-log4j12` JAR from the `spring-security` dependency.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
           <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**Note -** In some cases multiple dependencies have pulled in binding with the `slf4j-log4j12` JAR and you don't need to add exclude for each and every dependency that has pulled in.
You just have to do that add exclude dependency with the dependency which has been placed at first.

Ex -

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

If you work with gradle then add following code to your `build.gradle` file to exclude SLF4J binding from all the modules

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I just ignored/removed that jar file.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
<!--<dependency>-->
     <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
     <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>-->
<!--</dependency>-->
```

I solved by delete this:spring-boot-starter-log4j2

Comment: not clear: do you mean delete/comment above xml section, or add?

Answer (score 3):

Just use only required dependency, not all :))). For me, for normal work of logging process you need this dependency exclude others from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is issue because of StaticLoggerBinder.class class belongs to two different jars. this class references from logback-classic-1.2.3.jar and same class also referenced from log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar. both of jar in classpath. Hence there is conflict between them. 
This is reason of log file is not generation even though log4j2.xml  file in classpath [src/main/resource].

We have so select one of jar, I recommend use log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar file and exclude logback-classic-1.2.3.jar file.
Solution: open pom file and view the dependency Hierarchy [eclipse] or run
mvn dependency:tree command to find out the dependency tree and source of dependency that download the dependency. find the conflicting dependency and exclude them. For Springboot application try this.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

This is working fine for me after struggling a lots.
```

Answer (score 2):

...
    
        org.codehaus.mojo
        cobertura-maven-plugin
        2.7
        test
        
            
                ch.qos.logback
                logback-classic
            
            
                tools
                com.sun
            
        
      
                  ...

## I fixed with this

...
    
        org.codehaus.mojo
        cobertura-maven-plugin
        2.7
        test
        
            
                ch.qos.logback
                logback-classic
            
            
                tools
                com.sun
            
        
      
                  ...

Answer (score 2):

For me, it turned out to be an Eclipse/Maven issue after switch from log4j to logback. Take a look into your `.classpath` file and search for the string `"log4j"`.

In my case I had the following there:

`<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar" />`

Removing those entries from the file (or you could regenerate it) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer was to force a Maven rebuild. In Eclipse:

1. Right click on project-> Maven -> Disable Maven nature
2. Right click on project-> Spring Tools > Update Maven Dependencies
3. Right click on project-> Configure > Convert Maven Project

Comment: After number 1, the other options doesn´t appera anymore...thanks more things to fix

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going to Project Structure from my Intellij project.
I deleted the file named: Maven: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j-impl:2.14.1
[image]

This file is not shown in this picture. You may see two libraries mentioned as **log4j-to-slf4j**. Delete one and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

For all those looking for the solution for `spring-boot`-type dependencies, the magic incantation for Gradle is this:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
}
```

in your `build.gradle` at the top level (**not** inside the `dependencies` block).

All other solutions found in the interwebs (including the one here suggesting to exclude the `slf4j` module) did not work for me.

This is what I have in my `build.gradle` (snippet):

```
// Removes the annoying warning about the multiple SLF4J implementations:
//    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')

    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

    // Removes the annoying warning:
    // warning: unknown enum constant When.MAYBE
    //  reason: class file for javax.annotation.meta.When not found
    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain/31622432
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'

    // other stuff...
```

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my pom.xml i had both

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i deleted the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in a non-maven project, two depended jar each contained a slf4j. I solved
by remove one depended jar, compile the project(which of course getting failure) then add the removed one back.

Answer (score 0):

In case these logs are the result of this fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919375/2894819

When one of your libraries actually use it. And your application doesn't need SL4J just replace implementation to runtimeOnly.

```
// contains dependency to sl4j-api
implementation("com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-jvm:1.2.0")

// add this to remove both warnings
runtimeOnly("org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.36")
```

In that case when you run your app the actual dependency will be included once by the library and won't be included to the bundle of your application.jar itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 sources of dependencies for log4 one in C:\Program Files\smcf.ear directory and the second from maven which caused the multiple binding for sl4j.

Deleting the smcf.ear directory solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem but using `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ my-api --- 
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple
SLF4J providers. SLF4J: Found provider [org.slf4j.nop.NOPServiceProvider@2a32d6c]
SLF4J: Found provider [org.slf4j.jul.JULServiceProvider@7692d9cc]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual provider is of type [org.slf4j.nop.NOPServiceProvider@2a32de6c]
```

And after run `mvn dependency:tree` I find the problem:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.22.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.22.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.5.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.22.2:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-logger-api:jar:2.22.2:test
[INFO] ...
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6:test
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-webdav:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-jcr-commons:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:2.0.7:test
[INFO] |     |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:2.0.7:test
[INFO] |     |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:test
```

The package `org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14` is the cause and not `slf4j-api`  or `slf4j-log4j12`.

After exclude `slf4j-jdk14` dependency the problem is resolved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Now the build is clean without warnings:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ my-api ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running HexagonalTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] Time elapsed: 2.69 s - in MyTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.888 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-08T13:08:26-03:00
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
```

---

##### Reference:

- [slf4j version conflict while building with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477942/slf4j-version-conflict-while-building-with-maven)

Answer (score -1):

The combination of `<scope>provided</scope>` and `<exclusions>` didn't work for me.

I had to use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/empty.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Where `empty.jar` is a jar file with literally nothing in it.

Answer (score -5):

Seems removing .m2 directory and  :

`mvn install -DskipTests -T 4` resolved this issue for me.