# Jetty 9.1+: how to get my webapp logs with log4j/slf4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, jetty-9

I have a webapp running on Jetty 9.3.6 in `${jetty.base}` which is set to `/opt/mybase/`. My webapp uses `slf4j` and I use `log4j` as the actual logging framework, so the logging statements in my webapp source looks like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SillyClass
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger (SillyClass.class.getName ());

    ...

    public static void foo ()
    {
        if (error ())
        {
           log.error ("ERROR");
        }
        else
        {
           log.info ("NOT an error");
        }
   }

   ...

}
```

And in my gradle build file, I did this:

```
dependencies {

 ...
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'
 compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
 ...
}
```

This configuration works quite well for another (non-Jetty, non-webapp) Java project which uses the same logging framework; I can use `${project.home}/src/main/resources/log4j.properties` to control the output of the log.

Anyway, when I moved to Jetty, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-log4j.html) to the dot; but as soon as I did that, I hit the [multiple-bindings error](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings). To correct that, I removed the `slf4j` references in my gradle build file, but that resulted in the error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/start/Classpath$Loader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
```

I then removed all references to `slf4j` and `log4j` (commented out the three lines I show in my `build.gradle` above), but the error I see is still the same. What am I doing wrong?

My `/opt/mybase/resources/log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/opt/mybase/logs/jetty.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %l %m%n
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should give a try using just one dependency `compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'` instead all three

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings

Comment: That does not work: I don't see any logs again. I edited my OP for `log4j.properties` The multiple bindings message is back when I remove the `compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'` alone.

Comment: Also, please note that this is not an SLF4J and Log4J question; I know how to use both in Java projects (as mentioned in my OP). It may eventually turn out to be some subtlety, but it appears specifically about how Jetty handles that subtlety, not otherwise.

Comment: Are you configuring the Jetty server or writing the code for implementation   of Jetty server using the jetty dependency?

Comment: I am configuring Jetty server. In other words, I have a webapp `silly.war` which I place in `/opt/mybase/webapp/` and then start the jetty server using `/opt/mybase/webapp/ $ java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar`

Comment: I am using the jetty server wit my application and in gradle build I add only dependency  compile(group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.6')
    compile(group:'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-log4j12',version: '1.7.13')  and its work fine for me.

Comment: Actually, tried a few more things and the trouble I am having now is a crash somewhere else in Jetty. See http://pastebin.com/X14GjrKt. I saw this error earlier, but I saw it again now, and am raising it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a genuinely embarrassing error on my part. The main issue was not `log4j` or `slf4j` or configuration in jetty, I believe. I think that worked just fine. Also, despite multiple bindings, the jetty server actually chooses *something* shown here in the Jetty logs:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-443-webapp.war-_webapp-any-8458003046853847474.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12- 1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mybase/webapp/lib/logging/slf4j-log4j12-  1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an  explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Moreover, if a dependency has logging built in, you are out of luck, depending on how well maintained things are, I think you will have a clash anyway. At least, I know of no way to prevent this in that case.

Well, the real issue was that the webapp did not have its own `log4j.properties` (if you are using gradle, this would be in `$(projectHome)/src/main/resources/log4j.properties)`. I added that to my project and my logging makes a lot more sense (i.e., I see it where it should be, in `/opt/mybase/logs/my-silly-webapp-log.txt`).

Lastly, the crash I reported is unrelated (in the comments, on Dec 29) and has to do with Jetty 9.3.6 bug which is as yet unresolved, it appears, despite being called resolved in the Jetty bug db for 9.3.6. What threw me off was that the logs appeared immediately after the `multiple_bindings` error I reported originally. They are not related, it appears. I cannot track  down the exact bug in Jetty bug DB as I write this, but the last I checked  that bug (about a week ago), the issue was when the *Jetty* `log4j.properties` (in `/opt/mybase/resources/log4j.properties`) has set `rootLogger` to `DEBUG` (got that from the comments on that bug). I am able to reproduce the error (the websocket app itself just works fine, despite the Jetty log related crash) when my `rootLogger` in Jetty `log4j.properties` is set to `DEBUG`. By moving the `rootLogger` for *Jetty* `log4j.properties` to INFO or lower, I am able to confirm that the problem goes away. I will raise it in Jetty's bug DB.

Hope this helps someone.