# Spring 4 with maven build application is not deployed in tomcat 8 compiled using java 8 upgradation.Unable to resolve

Tags: java-8, tomcat8

The stack trace is:

```
21-Jan-2016 15:35:37.917 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable de
bug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time
and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Tomcat-8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Tomcat-8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.187 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be
 found in the appropriate container log file
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.224 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.233 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to hav
e started a thread named [AsyncAppender-asyncFlightsLogAppender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:231)
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.233 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to hav
e started a thread named [AsyncAppender-asyncFlightNotFoundRQRS] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:231)
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.234 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to hav
e started a thread named [AsyncAppender-asyncFlightSearchErrorAppender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:231)
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.234 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to hav
e started a thread named [AsyncAppender-asyncConsoleAppender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:231)
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.235 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to hav
e started a thread named [AsyncAppender-asyncMailAppender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:231)
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.244 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive D:\Tomcat-8\webapps\ROOT.war
has finished in 75,545 ms
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.246 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.253 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Jan-2016 15:36:38.254 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 75600 ms
```

log file:
 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.createMap(Log4jLogEvent.java:242)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.(Log4jLogEvent.java:147)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.DefaultLogEventFactory.createEvent(DefaultLogEventFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:366)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.log(Log4jLogger.java:375)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

If anybody encountered this problem before, please let me know.

Comment: *Server startup in 75600 ms* -  where is the error?

Comment: yes.application is not properly deployed. Does this cause any problem? "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings".

Comment: @stella check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings might help

Comment: @goodyzain thank you, that warning is not coming now, but a new error:

Comment: @stella then edit and show us the Error...which will be helpfull..in stack trace all we see is warning..Or you can clean tomcat directory....try once

Comment: I am unable to find the issue, it's working properly in jdk7 and tomcat 7