# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587; java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

After going through post provided for the same problem, I have written the following code. But I am getting the following exception :

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

```
package com.nura.mail;

import constants.Constants;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import logger.LoggerUtil;

/**
 *
 * @author Arun kumar
 */
public class SendMail implements Constants {

    private final static LoggerUtil log = new LoggerUtil();

    public static void main(String receiver, String msg, String header) {

        log.addLog("Entry in SendMail");
        final String username = "sendmailnotification";
        final String password = "version5.0";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(receiver));
            message.setSubject(header);
            message.setText(msg);
            Transport.send(message);
            log.addLog("Your mail has been sent");
            log.addLog("Exit from Send Mail");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.addLog(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SendMail.main("aprodigalboy@gmail.com", "test", "test");
        System.out.println("End of the program");
    }
}
```

I have created a signup form ,I get the email from the signup field and sending the OTP but i could not receive OTP due to this error

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NetBeans%208.0.1/java/modules/ext/hibernate4/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Ashok/Final/CloudArmour%20(2)/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Ashok/Final/CloudArmour%20(2)/lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   492 [main] INFO logger.LoggerUtil - Entry in SendMail
>   End of the program
>   22060 [main] INFO logger.LoggerUtil - Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587

Comment: You might have conflicts in your CLASS PATH, review that you're not referencing different versions of the same lib. Also, possible duplicate (with reference to maven): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings

Comment: I am new to this tech can you elaborate please?

Comment: See the [connection debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).