# log4j settings in Jetty

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

I have a java webapp that uses log4j to log messages.  This webapp is a wrapper around a jar file that I have written.  When I run my webapp through the built-in Jetty from Eclipse, my JAR's logs (LOG.info(...) messages) are printed out just fine.  Now, I have downloaded a standalone instance of Jetty and have run my web app from there.  With the default log4j settings packaged with Jetty, I am not able to see ANY logs from my JAR.  I only see the Jetty logs and the webapp's logs.

I have found the log4j.properties file under the resources folder, but am not sure what I need to change in it to get my app's logs to show.  I had thought that Jetty worked out of the box with basic log4j logging.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty doesn't use log4j.

You'll need to configure your `${jetty.base}` (Important Note: do not edit/modify/delete any content in `${jetty.home}`) to use slf4j first, log4j second.

```
$ cd /path/to/myjettybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=resources,ext
```

Next, go download `slf4j-api.jar`, `slf4j-log4j##.jar` (where `##` is the support version of log4j you want to use), and `log4j.jar` and put them in the new `${jetty.base}/lib/ext` directory.

Finally, put your `log4j.xml` in your `${jetty.base}/resources/` directory.

That's it, you've setup Jetty Distribution for log4j use.

Comment: Actually, I forgot I am using logback instead of log4j, but anyways... I added the logback jars and I am getting log messages saying multiple slf4j bindings have been found.

Comment: Forgot to elaborate... I am seeing some debug messages from my app, but the explicit LOG.info(...) messages are still not getting printed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings

Comment: You can't have app generated logging pass through the WebApp isolation layers.  You either have Server logging, or App logging, each configured separately, with different Appenders (and file locations!)

Comment: I updated my OP.  I just realized that the issue is not with my webapp, but a jar that is packaged with the webapp.  That jar's logging is not printed.