# Unable to start Jetty Server - Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/

Tags: maven, jetty, m2e, xacml

When running XACML-PAP-ADMIN and XACML-PAP-REST on Windows 10. Java jdk1.8.0_144. I get next error:

```
Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class from jar file:///D:/Projects/XACML/XACML-PAP-ADMIN/target/xacml-pap-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.11.0.jar
```

Comment: Can you ad some context? What command are you running? Or are you running it from Eclipse? And if yes, what is your "Run configuration"?

Comment: I am following these steps but ended of with the above error

There are 3 webapps that need to run. Easiest to start them in this order in separate terminal windows:

XACML-PAP-REST
Open a terminal window and cd to the XACML-PAP-REST subdirectory.

'mvn jetty:run-war'

By default it will be running at localhost:9090/pap

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362629/775715 - you need to be running Jetty 9.4.9 or newer to support the Java 9 features of newer JARs (like what `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar` brings to the table)

Comment: What tool are you using? Axiomatics does not run on Jetty.

Comment: I am using Apache Maven

Comment: What XACML engine?

Comment: I am running it on Java Eclipse.

Comment: here is the link of the project whom I follow...
https://github.com/att/XACML

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt But it should also support earlier jdk7 as well right? Is there any option other than upgrading the application server?

Answer (score 2):

That could be linked to your version of Jetty, considering it fails on log4j 2.11 jar.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46878035/6309):

> log4j 2.9 and later are [multi-release jars for Java 9](https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/log4j-2-9-released).

Make sure to use a Jetty compatible with that, or [use slf4j instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37657913/6309).

Comment: currently my jetty version is 9.3.20.I think first I need to update the jetty version may be it works?Can you please guide me how I am able to update to latest jetty version ? Should I need to update Pom.xml file if yes there where?

Comment: for further details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014779/unable-to-reach-local-host-via-terminal-window

Comment: @VonC But it should also support earlier jdk7 as well right? Is there any option other than upgrading the application server?

Comment: @gaurav the only other option is that you can downgrade your log4j to a version before log4j started producing JEP 238 JAR files. (which forces JEP 238 behavior on MANY other java projects and libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom DevMode JettyLauncher:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger;
import com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

import java.io.File;

public class DevModeJettyLauncher extends JettyLauncher {
    @Override
    protected WebAppContext createWebAppContext(TreeLogger logger, File appRootDir) {
        WebAppContext webAppContext = super.createWebAppContext(logger, appRootDir);
        webAppContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern", "none");//this is just a regex that matches nothing
        return webAppContext;
    }
}
```

And then configure it when launching.

Dev Mode Parameters: `-server <package>.DevModeJettyLauncher`