# Unable to reach local host via terminal window

Tags: maven, github, attr, maven-jetty-plugin, xacml3

I am using Apache Maven in Java eclipse to Run Xacml code but when I am going to access local Host I am stuck at **started jetty server** and ended up with the given error...

```
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:893)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class from jar file:///C:/Users/Ather/Desktop/Maven/XACML/XACML-PAP-REST/target/xacml-pap-rest-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.11.0.jar**
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass (AnnotationParser.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry (AnnotationParser.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@788e3702{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9090}
[INFO] Started @77593ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```