# Getting Application status failed after launching

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Here is my stderr.log file.

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/app/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/dtadmin/appcache/application_1474540741175_0001/filecache/104/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J:

See [this](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings) site for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type

[org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

I have tried

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

but still I am getting the same issue.

Anyone Please suggest something how can i resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

Comment: I have tried that..  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 

  </dependency>     but still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: That message is more a warning than an exception. The message says that in the classpath there are more than one jar that implement SLF4J. To resolve the issue you require to remove one of them from your classpath. This message is annoying but it is not why your application is failing.