# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings warning

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, slf4j

I've seen in other questions that usually the solution to this warning is to exclude slf4j from the dependency that causes this conflict, but I can't spot the problem in my project.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

I run `mvn dependency:tree` command and this is the output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ subscriptionsmanager ---
[INFO] it.pietro:subscriptionsmanager:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.5.13:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.15:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.15:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.12.7:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- de.bwaldvogel:mongo-java-server:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.bwaldvogel:mongo-java-server-core:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- de.bwaldvogel:mongo-java-server-memory-backend:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.15.0:test
[INFO] +- org.testcontainers:mongodb:jar:1.15.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.testcontainers:testcontainers:jar:1.15.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.20:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.rnorth.duct-tape:duct-tape:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.rnorth.visible-assertions:visible-assertions:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.github.docker-java:docker-java-api:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport-zerodep:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-swing-junit:jar:3.17.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-swing:jar:3.17.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.easytesting:fest-util:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.easytesting:fest-reflect:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] \- info.picocli:picocli:jar:4.5.2:compile
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand what dependency causes the conflict.

Comment: Given one of the paths mentioned is from Eclipse, I'd guess the problem is with Eclipse adding something extra on the path.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Can you give an example where Eclipse does this?

Comment: After changing the `pom.xml`, did you right-click the project and _Maven > Update Project..._? Please show the command line executed by Eclipse (in the run configuration there is a _Show Command Line_ button for that).

Comment: @howlger I can't, I don't use Eclipse, I just notice that both paths in the message are inside the Eclipse application, one of them OSGi, and one of m2eclipse. I guess the m2eclipse one is from Maven, I don't know where the OSGi one is coming from.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't believe Eclipse adds something extra on the path. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the issue by adding the following exclusion in the dependencies (of pom.xml) that caused conflict.

```
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
```

Comment: But I do not understand which dependency causes the conflict.

Comment: This does not work here because it is caused by Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

The **SLF4J bindings warning** comes from the Eclipse IDE itself and is **not related to your application** you write in the Eclipse IDE. So it's just **noise that can be ignored** (see e.g. [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473789#c1) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520754)).

I guess you have the *Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers* with maybe some additional plugins installed. That's more than 900 JARs. SLF4J is used by the Maven support for Eclipse (in the SLF4J bindings warning as `m2e`) and also by at least one other plugin in an incompatible way causing this warnings. Eclipse is based on OSGi where there is not a flat classpath and where plugins/bundles can be installed, started, stopped and uninstalled at runtime. SLF4J seems not to build with OSGi in mind, hence the misleading warning `Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings`, although there is no classpath in OSGi which uses its own class loader instead.