# Why got "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j, slf4j

When I run my Spring project I got error `SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.` in my ide console. I don't why this error is produce while run my project.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/*/fiserv/src/main/resources/CommerceConnect.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/rsawant/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.13/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/rsawant/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.10/logback-classic-1.2.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.
org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:164)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Here is pom.xml for reference

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fiserv.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>fiserv-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show me your dependecies

Comment: I have added Pom.xml in question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings)